# Is it bad practice to specify Web Service "list" type to always have at least one item in XSD/WSDL?

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl

I've come across with lots of specifications like one below:

```
<xs:complexType name="SomeTypeList">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="some" type="SomeType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

in message specification the list itself is optional (minOccusr="0").

The style above means that if list if present it always has items.

But is this really better than specifying list as mandatory and allowing it to be empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it as this other conundrum: when you're building an API method (Java, .NET, PHP, etc.) that is looking for a list that may not have any members, should you return null or an empty list?

Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Windows), as an example; is says: *If there are no files in the DirectoryInfo, this method returns an empty array.*

Or [this](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IMethod.html) (in Java): *Returns the type signatures of the exceptions this method throws, in the order declared in the source, an empty array if this method throws no exceptions*.

Or best practices regarding the return or null values in general... or [this one](http://www.garfieldtech.com/blog/empty-return-values) related to PHP (random pick from Google, not affiliated with it): *The original question is one of predictability: If you have a function that return an array of things, and there are no things to return, you should return an empty array. Not false, not NULL, an empty array. Why? Because I want to foreach() over it.*

Looks good for APIs; but what if you're looking at the XML's "beauty" criteria... it may seem ugly and useless to have a hoard of empty XML tags for all those lists that are empty...

I would say the answer is conjectural.

My vote... in XSDs, I would first try NOT to model a list as shown in your sample; if reuse is needed, go with a group. Having a list type on top of a repeating element, has the tendency of generating funky APIs when you bind the XSD to Code. Plus, if your XSD's complexity is somehow measured by the depth or your tree (at least I do a lot of complexity metrics analysis), you're obviously added one level for nothing.

I would only do it if I have to support xsd:all; In which case, I would follow exactly what you've shown in the snippet. This way, you know that every tag on the wire has a *raison d'être*.